# Bitmap saved in internal storage doesn't show on Gallery

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-gallery

I created a simple app to save a bitmap in internal storage and be able to show this bitmap in the android gallery like any other image.

The problem is: it isn't showing in the gallery after is saved... and I don't know what I am doing wrong. (I'm testing this on emulator)

**Here is my class that handles the save of the Bitmap**. This Saver class is used in my main activity when I click on a button saves the bitmap.

```
public class Saver {

private Context mContext;
private String mNameOfFolder = "Storager";
private String mNameOfFile = "Quote";

public void saveImage(Context context, Bitmap imageToSave) {
    mContext = context;

    // Create the directory
    File dir = mContext.getDir(mNameOfFolder, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String filePath = dir.getAbsolutePath();

    // Get the current date and time to attach to the name of the image
    String currentDateAndTime = getCurrentDateAndTime();

    if(!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }

    File file = new File(dir, mNameOfFile + currentDateAndTime + ".jpg");

    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        imageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);

        out.flush();
        out.close();

        galleryAddPic(file);

        successSave();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("d", "file not found");
        unableToSave();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("d", "IO Exception");
        unableToSave();
    }
}

private void galleryAddPic(File file) {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    mContext.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}

private String getCurrentDateAndTime() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    // Setting format of the time
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss");
    // Getting the formated date as a string
    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

    return formattedDate;
}
```

}

I even added the method galleryAddPic() that is provided by android developer site [here](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskGallery) to be able to add the image to Media Provider's database, making it available in the Android Gallery application and to other apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Third-party apps, including the `MediaStore`, have no access to your app's [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). If you want third-party apps to have access to the file, use [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

Also, I have no idea why you are creating a `ContextWrapper` here. If you have methods that require a `Context` (e.g., `getDir()` in your current code), call them on the `Context` that is passed into your method.

Comment: edited the ContextWrapper issue ... (I must have been sleeping while coding ...)

So the external storage from what I read it isn't only sd cards right?

Comment: @Cap.Alvez: [External storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) is rarely [removable storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). On the vast majority of Android devices, external storage is part of the on-board flash, as is internal storage. The difference is that external storage is public (with the proper permissions), while internal storage is private.

Comment: I'm a bit confused now. What should I use as path to save on external storage? I wanted to create a folder with the name of the application with the bitmaps inside but still be able to see them in the default android gallery. Should I use for example the `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` ? Cuz if I use that is pointing me to "/storage/sdcard" and it gives me fileNotFoundException.

Comment: @Cap.Alvez: "What should I use as path to save on external storage?" -- this is covered in [the blog post that I linked to](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). "Cuz if I use that is pointing me to "/storage/sdcard" and it gives me fileNotFoundException" -- I do not know what "it" is. If you are testing on an emulator, make sure that your AVD configuration has external storage.

Comment: Figured the problem: My AVD didn't had external storage correctly configured. Thanks, nice blog btw.